# HBase not connecting to ZooKeeper

Tags: hadoop, hbase, apache-zookeeper

I am struggling for getting my HBase shell running. 
It throws me the above exception in subject line. I have checked that hbase-site.xml matches perfectly with hadoop one.

Please help. I am struggling for 2 days and have a project due. I am attaching the two xml files of hadoop and hbase.

**hbase-site.xml**

```
    <configuration>
      <property>
        <name>hbase.rootdir</name>    
        <value>hdfs://localhost:54310/hbase</value>
        </property>
     <property>
     <name>hbase.zookeeper.property.dataDir</name>
     <value>/home/hduser/zookeeper</value>
    </property>

    <property>
      <name>hbase.zookeeper.property.clientPort</name>
      <value>2222</value>
      <description>Property from ZooKeeper's config zoo.cfg.
      The port at which the clients will connect.
      </description>
    </property>

    <property>
      <name>hbase.zookeeper.quorum</name>
      <value>localhost</value>
      <description>Comma separated list of servers in the ZooKeeper Quorum.
      </description>
    </property>

    </configuration>
```

**Core-site.xml**

```
  <configuration>
    <property>
      <name>hadoop.tmp.dir</name>
      <value>/app/hadoop/tmp</value>
      <description>A base for other temporary directories.</description>
    </property>

    <property>
      <name>fs.default.name</name>
      <value>hdfs://localhost:54310</value>
      <description>The name of the default file system.</description>
    </property>    
  </configuration>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

make sure zookeeper is running on 2222 port and there should be entery in zookeeper/conf/zoo.cfg

```
# the port at which the clients will connect
clientPort=2222
```

or make it 2181, start zookeeper by `./zkServer.sh start`
and change this default port in hbase-site.xml

```
   <property>
      <name>hbase.zookeeper.property.clientPort</name>
      <value>2181</value>
   </property>
```

Comment: Thank a lot for answering.
This problem was resolved. I was using HBase for hadoop 1, not 2.

Comment: However, I ran into different error now. Please have a look - 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29176273/the-node-hbase-unsecure-is-not-in-zookeeper-check-the-value-configured-in-zoo

Comment: interesting, i had to add this for phoenix 4 but not for phoenix 5